# Does SQLAlchemy support Query Notifications of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, flask, push-notification, sqlalchemy, query-notifications

Does SQLAlchemy support Query Notifications of SQL Server?
If not, what is the closest one could get?

I can imagine I could probably get SQLAlchemy directly submit Trasact SQL queries to set up the query notifications, but is there any more generic way?

In the end what I want is to be informed of any changes to the database that affects my query. This is for a FLASK web server that should then in turn push the updates to the clients showing some calculated information.

Comment: Have you considered the use of events ([core](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html) or [ORM](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html)) ?